# Request method POST enviando un String

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy intentando realizar un POST a través de una url enviando un String como parámetro, aunque no encuentro un metodo json para parsear ese string.

```
When('solicito generar remitos para pedidos con fecha {string}', function (fechaPedido) {
   // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
   let res;
   try {
      res = request('POST', ${url}/remitos, { json : { fechaPedido } });  // aquí el string fechaPedido
      console.log(res.getBody('utf8'));   //no llega a imprimir este console.log
      response = JSON.parse(res.getBody('utf8'));

      if (response.StatusCode == 200) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return assert.fail(response.StatusText);
      }

   } catch (error) {
      return assert.fail(error.message); // sale por aquí 
   }
});
```

En la clase que recibe el String "fechaPedido" lo imprimo y sale "null".

Comment: Si quieres enviar parametros por URL la peticion GET se especializa en eso, no deberias usar una peticion POST para enviar parametros por URL, deberias usar una peticion GET, de todas maneras aun asi se puede enviar parametros de URL por POST, pero se reciben como si fueran parametros GET en el backend.

Comment: por que el JSON va con llaves? no seria: {"json": fechaPedido} en vez de { json : { fechaPedido } }

Comment: @Srsole exacto, buen ojo, lo que tiene el OP creo que es redundante...

Comment: "En la clase que recibe el String "fechaPedido" lo imprimo y sale "null"". que clase?, porfavor agrega la clase...

Comment: Buenas tardes y gracias por sus respuestas. Como menciona Srsole efectivamente, el JSON va con llaves. Por otro lado, como menciona Riven  el POST lo hago porque, el enunciado del problema indica que "Se deben generar remitos hasta la fecha dada". El POST lo utilizo para generar esos remitos. Logré solucionarlo parseando el String en la clase que recibe este parámetro

`public String generarRemitos(String fechaArmado) throws IOException {
    Date cal;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

      cal = sdf.parse(mapper.readValue(fechaArmado, String.class));`